# Receiving a GCM notification inside Android service

Tags: android, android-service, google-cloud-messaging

I have a `Service` that runs alongside my main application. The purpose of this service is to synchronize with a main server in the background. In order to avoid constantly polling the main server for updates, I have implemented google cloud messaging to notify the app when there are changes to be downloaded.

When I place the `GcmBroadcastReceiver` class in my main package, it receives the notification fine. However, I'd like this to be received by my service, so it can then trigger a `downloadChanges()` function also inside the serivce. I don't really want the app to pick up the notification, then have to use `IPC` to communicate with the service - that seems a bit overcomplicated.

Is there a way for my service to receive the GCM notification, instead of the main app?

Currently my code is like this:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

// lots of other stuff in this class

    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM received!");
            downloadChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when receiving the GCM notification. What's the correct way for my background service to handle a GCM notification?

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.appnl.myapp.CustomApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- android.name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" -->

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.appnl.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="service.SyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/service_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="service.SyncService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

<!-- activity list -->
```

Logcat:

```
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.appnl.myapp-1.apk
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2493)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.appnl.myapp-1.apk
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2488)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    ... 10 more
```

Edit: I should add that my service is in a *separate* package to my main package. I have a feeling that is what is causing the problem, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Where do you get `ClassNotFoundException`? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: @Teifi : Slightly confused by a few things. **"I have a Service that runs alongside my main application."** for example. Are you saying you saying you've created two separate apps (i.e., apk files)?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. It's just a normal service instantiated within the app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is the naming of the receiver in your manifest. Because it is an inner class it needs to include the outer class name and have its name appended separated by $. Example...

```
com.appnl.myapp.SyncService$GcmBroadcastReceiver
```

In saying that however, I'm not sure this is a good way to do things.

Firstly the life-cycle of a `BroadcastReceiver` is as long as the `onReceive(...)` method executes and that method should only do minimal work. Unless your `downloadChanges()` method simply starts an asynchronous operation of some sort (and so returns immediately) you'll block the `onReceive(...)` method.

Secondly your approach assumes the `Service` is running permanently. If that is actually the case and you can guarantee it will continue to run then that's fine but you may be risking a lot of battery drain.

If you don't need a permanently running `Service` then I'd personally keep the `BroadcastReceiver` separate and use an `IntentService` instead. You'd then simply receive the broadcast and then in `onReceive(...)` use `startService(...)`. This would ensure the `BroadcastReceiver` has a short life and an `IntentService` uses its own worker thread (thus avoiding a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`) and it will also self-terminate after it has completed its work.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive input. The service is a sticky service so it will be running most of the time - however battery drain is a big consideration for me. I've put in checks to make sure the sync doesn't happen too often, and is a fairly lightweight class in other respects. The sync process inside the service will be asynchronous too so I'm not worried about blocking the UI thread. Thank you for your input, I will try including the outer class in the manifest.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't get it to work. :( I'm a little confused with what I need to change in my manifest. I've attached it to the question as an edit if you want to have a quick peek.

Comment: @Teifi : I was away from my computer for a while so didn't see your comment and edit to your question. I see you got an answer in the other question though - glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Yes, I need to apologize though. Your original answer was correct. However when I tried it, the app was still crashing, but I did not check the actual exception to make sure it was still a `ClassNotFoundException`. It was in fact something else, therefore I assumed your answer had not worked! It did work but I was getting an `InstantiationException` after that. I found out that the inner class needed to be static. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Teifi : No need for an apology - I know what it's like to sometimes focus on one piece of code only to find there's another piece of code  which is causing problems.